# SSRS positioning of an image

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm developing an SSRS report where I need to place three images (company logos) at the top of the page. I get the images from three table fields. This fields can be null (images are not mandatory to be present). The locations of the images are top left, top center and top right.

I cannot find a way to align an image to the right or center. Have any of you accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible to directly do auto-align / docking. For my reports, I set the report size to fit in a standard paper size. Then, if I know the size of the image, it is easy to position it in a static manner.

If this does not work for you, it is possible to use **custom code and element padding**. Please see this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/10/27/centeredimages.aspx). HTH.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead.

Comment: Link as [saved on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109134407/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/10/27/centeredimages.aspx) (internet archive), and on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chrishays/centered-images) (not to trusted - MS will change the link again or remove it completely it if they can confuse their customers or make more money out of doing that).

Answer (score 2):

I followed the advice on http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/nathaneccles/2014/04/15/ssrs-right-and-centre-align-images-in-a-table for Padding expressions for a 'FitProportional' image control adapting slightly as I had an image coming from a database and I needed a horizontally and vertically centered image in a 7.5cm square image control (this is roughly 212pts).

```
Left =CSTR(round((212 - (round((System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(First(Fields!LogoColourSmall.Value, "DS_Title"), Byte()))).Width*0.75) / ((System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(First(Fields!LogoColourSmall.Value, "DS_Title"), Byte()))).Height*0.75)/212),0))) / 2, 0)) + "pt"

Top =CSTR(round((212 - (round((System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(First(Fields!LogoColourSmall.Value, "DS_Title"), Byte()))).Height*0.75) / ((System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(First(Fields!LogoColourSmall.Value, "DS_Title"), Byte()))).Width*0.75)/212),0))) / 2, 0)) + "pt"
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method I have used is to insert a 3 column matrix inside a merged cell. The image can be placed inside the middle column.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a table at the top of your page and your images in a column of the header row? Use blank columns between the pics for space between them.

[image]

If a pic is missing, it won't affect the others.

Comment: I would like to move upside down an BinaryData, but does not work.