# Vertically center image in tablix

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS, when I have a tablix where rows can grow dynamically (so the row heights can differ) and this tablix has an image column, is it possible to center each image vertically?

I think one approach could be to set the image top padding dynamically via expression but then I would need to know the current row height which I'm not able to get, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS positioning of an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819820/ssrs-positioning-of-an-image)

Comment: This should point you  in the right direction
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/archive/2014/04/15/ssrs-right-and-centre-align-images-in-a-table.aspx